# Loop through file extensions

Tags: vb.net, file, loops, picturebox

```
Try
    Dim lImage As Image = Image.FromFile(appPath + "\" + "ActiveDisplay" + "\" + "Helmets" + "\" + vData + **"extension loop need"**)
    ResizePicture(Me.PictureBox1, lImage)
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I'm searching for a image name in viewer and need to loop through extensions
any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1639/looping#t=201608231708070683181

Comment: you need an actual loop construct (For Each, For n), `Image.FromFile` wont load wildcards and if it did what would be the point - you can only see one image at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a String array and a For Each

```
    Dim extensions As String() = {".png", ".jpg", ".bmp"}
    For Each ext As String In extensions
        Dim file As String = appPath + "\" + "ActiveDisplay" + "\" + "Helmets" + "\" + vData + ext

        'I recomend use:  Dim file As String= String.Format("{0}\ActiveDisplay\Helmets\{1}\{2}", appPath, vData, ext)

        If IO.File.Exists(file) Then
            Dim lImage As Image = Image.FromFile(file)
        End If
    Next
```